# How to implement HTTP protocol using WebRTC?

Tags: http, download, webrtc

Is it possible to implement the following scenario?

A browser client uses WebRTC to implement the necessary HTTP interface to serve a file.

A second browser client (without WebRTC capabilities) makes an HTTP Get request to the first browser and gets the file just like if it was stored in a traditional server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can't start exchanging data or media on a WebRTC connection until the secure RTP (SRTP) channel is set up. If a browser can't set up an SRTP connection then it can't communicate with another WebRTC peer.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are going to have to serve the page as HTTPS **only if** you require to access user's media streams, though it is good practice to serve page as HTTPS
2. WebRTC is meant to peer-to-peer, it cannot work if one end( receiver) does not support the tech, workaround would be use webserver acting as peer for one and proxy for other, but that would defeat the whole purpose, you might as well go with websockets